# calling setTimeout to decrease value

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I created a tool that checks a password strength. the result is given as a number between 0 to 100. to make things nicer, I created a `setTimeout` function to make the numbers increase or decrease gradually like a counter.

here is a link to the [full code in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PKR9Q/)

you will notice that the function works properly when the value increases but not when the value decreases. I believe the problem is in this piece of code:

```
function run() {
    var i = lastGrade;

    setTimeout( function updateProgress() {
        x.style.width = i*1.5 + 'px';
        s.innerHTML = i + '%';
        if(lastGrade <= grade) {
            if (i < grade){
                setTimeout(updateProgress, 10);
            }
            i++;
        }
        else if(lastGrade > grade) {
            if (i > grade){
                setTimeout(updateProgress, 10);
            }
            i--;
        }
    }, 10);
}
```

Comment: This password strength checker seem not to work properly. Test it with `123456789`. http://www.passwordmeter.com/

Comment: You are right, im still working on that issue... but I right now im trying to figure out another problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are updating `lastGrade` before the timeouts run.  This was actually affecting both the up and down meter animation, but was more apparent on the decreasing animation.

A more functional example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/MrywR/

However, you'll probably want to tweak the code so that `lastGrade` is used as the animation meter, to keep the bar from bouncing.

Changed code:

```
setTimeout( function updateProgress() {
    x.style.width = i*1.5 + 'px';
    s.innerHTML = i + '%';
    if(lastGrade <= grade) {
        if (i < grade){
            setTimeout(updateProgress, 10);
        } else {
            lastGrade = grade;
        }
        i++;
    }
    else if(lastGrade > grade) {
        if (i > grade){
            setTimeout(updateProgress, 10);
        } else {
            lastGrade = grade;
        }
        i--;
    }
}, 10);
```

---

**Update**

This version handles the animation much better overall: http://jsfiddle.net/5yeP7/1/

It handles quick typing, removes some unnecessary closures, and encapsulates the methods as local variables.

Comment: Works great but when type too quickly, it always shows 0 percent

Comment: I've created a different version that's much cleaner.  See the update.

Comment: Pressing a key for long time gives unwanted result.

Comment: Great answer @OverZealous! I love the update (you got +1), and by the way @Hoque the only reason for the unwanted result for pressing a key for long time is that repeated characters are decreasing the grade to zero.